# Tools.jar is not in Android Studio classpath (Windows 7)

Tags: android

I have changed the System variable to JAVA_HOME and my path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
and JAVA_HOME = that path so what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Just set JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are confusing JDK with JRE ? They are 2 different things. I made this error myself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I was mistakenly changing the installation folder for the JRE and not for the JDK.
The JDK was installed in C:\Program Files\Java...

Check that folder for the JDK files.

Answer (score 0):

Even after entering JDK path in JAVA_HOME if it does not work, try manually copy pasting tools.jar from JDK_Folder_path/lib to AndroidStudio_FolderPath/lib folder

Remember to redo these steps when you have android studio update. I had to spend time doing this twice in 7 month period.